# How to save video file using canvas on android?

Tags: android, android-layout

Currently I'm working on video effects like thermal, mono, etc.. for that I'm using preview callback with canvas stuff.

Can anyone please tell me how to save this video?

Below I have my callback code:

```
mCamera.setPreviewCallback(new PreviewCallback() {
                public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data1, Camera _camera) 
                {
                    Camera.Parameters parameters = _camera.getParameters();
                    parameters.setColorEffect(Camera.Parameters.EFFECT_NONE);
                    previewSize = parameters.getPreviewSize();
                    int frameSize = previewSize.width * previewSize.height;
                    int height = previewSize.height;
                    int width = previewSize.width;
                    int pixel;  
                    int A, R, G, B;
                    final double GS_RED = 0.299;
                    final double GS_GREEN = 0.587;
                    final double GS_BLUE = 0.114;
                    int[] rgba = new int[frameSize+1];

                    data = data1;

                         for (int i = 0; i < height; i++) 
                             for(int j = 0; j < width; j++) 
                             { 
                                 int y = (0xff & ((int) data[i * previewSize.width + j])); 
                                 int u = (0xff & ((int) data[frameSize + (i >> 1) * previewSize.width + (j & ~1) + 0])); 
                                 int v = (0xff & ((int) data[frameSize + (i >> 1) * previewSize.width + (j & ~1) + 1])); 

                                 y = y < 16 ? 16 : y;

                                 int r = Math.round(1.164f * (y - 16) + 1.596f * (v - 128)); 
                                 int g = Math.round(1.164f * (y - 16) - 0.813f * (v - 128) - 0.391f * (u - 128)); 
                                 int b = Math.round(1.164f * (y - 16) + 2.018f * (u - 128));

                                 r = r < 0 ? 0 : (r > 255 ? 255 : r); 
                                 g = g < 0 ? 0 : (g > 255 ? 255 : g); 
                                 b = b < 0 ? 0 : (b > 255 ? 255 : b);

                                rgba[i * previewSize.width + j] = 0xff000000 + (b << 16) + (g<< 8) + r;
                         }

                      Bitmap bmp = Bitmap.createBitmap(width, height,
                      Bitmap.Config.RGB_565);
                      bmp.setPixels(rgba, 0 , width , 0, 0, width, height);


                    // scan through every single pixel
                        for(int x = 0; x < width; ++x) {
                            for(int y = 0; y < height; ++y) {
                                // get one pixel color
                                pixel = bmp.getPixel(x, y);
                                // retrieve color of all channels
                                A = Color.alpha(pixel);
                                R = Color.red(pixel);
                                G = Color.green(pixel);
                                B = Color.blue(pixel);
                                // take conversion up to one single value
                                R = G = B = (int)(GS_RED * R + GS_GREEN * G + GS_BLUE * B);
                                // set new pixel color to output bitmap
                                bmp.setPixel(x, y, Color.argb(A, R, G, B));
                            }
                        }

                      canvas = mHolder.lockCanvas(); 
                      if (canvas != null) 
                      {
                          canvas.drawBitmap(bmp, (canvas.getWidth() - width) / 4, (canvas.getHeight() - height) / 4, null);
                          mHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(canvas); 
                      } 
                      bmp.recycle();
                }
            });
```

Answer (score 0):

You can save each frames and then can merge them with ffmpeg to encode , to create a video file.